# preseed.cfg ignoring hostname setting

Tags: debian, hostname, netcfg, preseed

I am installing Debian Wheezy (netinstall) in VirtualBox using `preseed.cfg`.

I tried both `d-i netcfg/get_hostname string somehost` and `d-i netcfg/get_hostname string somehost`, but in both cases the host gets set as "debian". I tried both at the same time but still the host is set as "debian".

Excerpt from [Debian's guide about preconfiguration file](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apbs04.html.en):

> If you want to force a hostname, regardless of what either the DHCP
>   server returns or what the reverse DNS entry for the IP is,
>   uncommentand adjust the following line
>
> d-i netcfg/hostname string somehost

Is this a bug or am I just unlucky?

Comment: Trying `d-i netcfg/get_hostname string somehost` twice doesn't really make sense. Should the question be updated with one occurance being `d-i netcfg/hostname string somehost`? In which case it would probably answer itself...

Answer (score 11):

If you are netbooting (with PXE and friends), the hostname is set up before fetching the preseed file, so the hostname should be set on the kernel command-line like this :

```
hostname=myhostname domain=mydomain
```

From the [introduction of the appendix B](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs01.html.en) (on preseeding) of the debian-installer manual :

> An important difference between the preseeding methods is the point at which the preconfiguration file is loaded and processed. For initrd preseeding this is right at the start of the installation, before the first question is even asked. For file preseeding this is after the CD or CD image has been loaded. For network preseeding it is only after the network has been configured.

Comment: While the answer was more true when posted, the use of aliases for hostname and domain is broken. Use the long form `netcfg/get_hostname=unassigned-hostname netcfg/get_domain=unassigned-domain` instead. Please see https://bugs.debian.org/1031643 for details. To actually solve the original posters problem though, `netcfg/hostname=myhostname netcfg/domain=mydomain` is likely the right arguments.

Comment: Fixed with https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/News/2023/20230428

Answer (score 10):

**Not a solution but a workaround**

I too have faced a similar issue and I worked around it by setting the host name after installation via the following lines added at the end of my `pressed.cfg`:

```
d-i pressed/late_command string\
    in-target /bin/bash -c 'echo desired_name > /etc/hostname'
```

The `in-target` is necessary so that the `/` refers to the target filesystem (that will eventually become your root filesystem) that usually appears as `/target` during installation.

Comment: I've also used this but with a slight modification so that the hostname is automatically set from a DNS lookup: `d-i pressed/late_command string in-target /bin/bash -c 'echo $(dig +short -x $(facter ipaddress)) | sed -e \'s/\.$//\' > /etc/hostname'`.  This uses "facter" from puppetlabs to get the IP address but you could do something similar using `ip addr` and `sed`.

Answer (score 5):

I found that this problem went away when I removed `priority=critical` from the arguments I was passing-in to the kernel at the net install command line (via the pxelinux.cfg directory entries).

I assume this means that the question which asks the hostname has been given a priority which is lower than 'critical', and so gets populated with the default answer.

If you do make this change, you may find that you have to preseed some other lower-than-critical answers for other questions later on in the install process...

Answer (score 5):

It's debian-installer limitation. By the time you fetch your preseed config file from network, `netcfg` has already done it's job and is gone, so it won't refetch values.

[somewhat offical kludge](http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/manual/en.i386/apbs04.html#preseed-network) is to use in your `preseed.cfg` line:

```
d-i preseed/run string http://example.net/d-i/jessie/preseed.sh
```

and in that `preseed.sh` then specify:

```
#!/bin/sh
kill-all-dhcp; netcfg
```

That way, when network is established and `preseed.cfg` is fetched, `preseed.sh` will also be fetch and run, so it will restart `netcfg` which will then read all preseed values for `netcfg/*` and configure them correctly (`/etc/hostsname`, `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/network/interfaces` if you're setting static IP configuration via preseed etc)

Comment: You can do this without a separate file: `d-i preseed/early_command string kill-all-dhcp; netcfg` in your preseed file is enough. Tested with Stretch in an automated netinstall.